# In Rails how do I turn off an email reminder job

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a client complaining about email reminders being sent out. So I've looked through the code and I think there are a couple of locations I can probably try and address.

Reminder Emails Controller which as:

```
class Admin::ReminderEmailsController < Admin::ApplicationController

def edit
 @system_email = SystemEmail.first
end

def update
 @system_email = SystemEmail.first
 flash[:notice] = 'System Email updated successfully' if @system_email.update_attributes(system_email_params)
 respond_with @system_email, location: admin_system_emails_path
end

private

def system_email_params
  params.require(:system_email)
       .permit(:reminder_content)
end
end
```

Users Controller that includes:

```
  def send_training_email(user)
   future_date = DateTime.current + 10.days
   TrainingReminderJob.set(wait_until: future_date).perform_later(user)
 end
```

Training Reminder Jobs

```
class TrainingReminderJob < ApplicationJob
 queue_as :default

 def perform(user)
  UserAgentMailer.training_reminder(user).deliver_later
 end
end
```

My inclination is to just mess with training reminder jobs as it seems the least invasive. Would just adding in under perform be enough?:

```
UserAgentMailer.perform_deliveries = false
```

Comment: removing the perform deliveries is going to just disable the sent, but the job and processing will be still done and it's unnecesary, why don't you just go where the method 'send_training_email' is called and remove it so the job isn't even created

Comment: I agree with xploshioOn. If you're looking to remove sending those emails all together then do so and remove the calls to the mailer where they appear in your code. If you're worried you'll want to add them back you can always comment them out for now. A better fix would be to add an option for the user to disable reminders for themselves so they're dropped from the email but others still recieve.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you would add a boolean column to the User model such as `skip_reminder_email` and make it admin and/or user changeable through your UI.  Then test for that in your `send_training_email` method.

```
$ rails g migration AddSkipReminderEmailToUser skip_reminder_email:boolean
$ rake db:migrate
```

then in your method:

```
def send_training_email(user)
  unless user.skip_reminder_email
    future_date = DateTime.current + 10.days
    TrainingReminderJob.set(wait_until: future_date).perform_later(user)
  end
end
```

Again, you need a way for the admin or user to update the `skip_reminder_email` boolean to true or false.  To test in development though, you could just update the flag from the rails console:

```
irb> User.find(user_id).update(skip_reminder_email: true)
```

And then run the controller action in UsersController that calls `send_training_email`.

Comment: A better place to put the test would probably be wherever you call `send_training_email` in your controller, but you haven't shown us that code.